# Where should I put portaudio so that Pyaudio can find it

Tags: python, makefile, gentoo, portaudio, pyaudio

Working on Gentoo (on the robot Nao) that has no make and no gcc on it, it is really hard for me to install portaudio. I managed to put pyaudio in the right location so that python can detect it but whenever I try "import pyaudio" it asks me to install portaudio first.
i have a virtual machine running gentoo emulating the robot where gcc and make are available. I could compile portaudio on that machine but then after copying its content to the robot I cannot run make install. Where should I put each library file exactly so that pyAudio can find it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I could find the source of the problem. Somehow portaudio is installing itself to /usr/local/ but the robot I'm working on uses the folders in /usr i.e /usr/lib /usr/include and not /usr/local/lib etc.
Putting the libraries in /usr/lib and also transferring manually some portaudio libs you can find in python site-packages folder solved the problem.

Comment: When you use portage to do the installing you don't run into these issues ;)  You should change the --prefix folder when running configure to specify /usr as the destdir instead of /usr/local which is probably the default or what you entered.  You can also get around the problem by adjusting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH but I digress.

Comment: There is no portage installed on the robot.